# text rendering artifact when rendering in 3D opengl GLfW

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw

Main.cpp

```
//Variables
const unsigned int width = 896, height = 504;

//Initiating GLFW Window
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

//Creating a GLFW window
window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Jaguar", NULL, NULL);

//Checking if Window was initiated
if (window == NULL) {
    std::cout << "GLFW FAILED TO INITIATE WINDOW!\n";
    glfwTerminate();
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

//Centering Window 
int windowWidth, windowHeight;
glfwGetWindowSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
glfwSetWindowPos(window, mode->width / 2 - windowWidth / 2, mode->height / 2 - windowHeight / 2);

//Setting-Up window's icon
GLFWimage icon[1];
icon[0].pixels = stbi_load("resources/images/gui/icon/icon.png", &icon[0].width, &icon[0].height, 0, 4);
glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 1, icon);
stbi_image_free(icon[0].pixels);

//Checking if Glad was initiated
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
    std::cout << "GLAD FAILED TO BE INITIATED\n";
}

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

//Setting-Up Viewport
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

//Intitiating MainMenu
states.push(new MainMenuState(*window, &states));
```

font.cpp

```
FT_Library ft;

if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
    std::cout << "FREETYPE::Failed to initialize library\n";
}
FT_Face face;
if (FT_New_Face(ft, filePath, 0, &face)) {
    std::cout << "FREETYPE::Failed to load to font: " << filePath << "\n";
}

// set size to load glyphs as
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, px);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 128; c++) {

    if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
        std::cout << "FREETYPE::Failed to load glpyh\n";
    }
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, face->glyph->bitmap.width,
        face->glyph->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    Character character = {
    texture,
    glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
    glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top)
    ,face->glyph->advance.x };

    Characters.insert(std::pair<char, Character>(c, character));
}
FT_Done_Face(face);
FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
```

text.cpp

```
// activate corresponding render state  
shader.use();
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.id, "textColor"), color.x, color.y, 
color.z);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// iterate through all characters
std::string::const_iterator c;
for (c = string.begin(); c != string.end(); c++)
{
   
    Character ch = font.Characters[*c];
   
    float xpos = position.x + ch.bearing.x * scale;
    float ypos = position.y - (ch.size.y - ch.bearing.y) * scale;

    float w = ch.size.x * scale;
    float h = ch.size.y * scale;
    // update VBO for each character
    float vertices[6][4] = {
        { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0f, 0.0f },
        { xpos,     ypos,       0.0f, 1.0f },
        { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0f, 1.0f },

        { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0f, 0.0f },
        { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0f, 1.0f },
        { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0f, 0.0f }
    };
    // render glyph texture over quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.textureId);
    // update content of VBO memory
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // render quad
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    // now advance cursors for next glyph (note that advance is number of 
1/64 pixels)
    position.x += (ch.advance >> 6) * scale; // bitshift by 6 to get value in 
pixels (2^6 = 64)
}
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: There is a box because you're rendering the text over the scene.

Comment: @a_donda Is there a way to just render the text and have the box transparent?

Comment: Are you correct use alpha blending? Are you draw text last? And are you have alpha in texture?

Comment: Yes. But the freetype pages and numerous examples explain that exhaustively. Also, you don't want to have blending enabled all the time. Here's how text rendering can go: extract glyphs, assemble font texture/s, assemble static buffer/s for fixed text. Enter loop: assemble dynamic buffer/s for per frane text, render scene, enable alpha blending, render text, diable alpha blending, next frame.

Comment: @a_donda I understand the article im just not sure if im over seeing something like if i forgot to enable something at the current moment performance is not a concern right now

Comment: Show the code of your shader.

Comment: @d3m4nz3 Im using the shader provided by the learn opengl: https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=includes/learnopengl/shader.h

Comment: That's the C++ code used to load the shaders, not the source code of the shaders. The shaders are the files written in GLSL language. Since you obviously didn't write them yourself, there's little chance that there is a problem in there, though.

Comment: @d3m4nz3: Shaders are in there. The example does work, Imo, OP has problems with OpenGL state. I suggest to first run the learnopengl code (which it does right away), then combine it with a scene. If problems occur then, they can ask again naming the *changes* they did. The snippets shown are just learnopengl code, the errors are elsewhere (probably in the sequence of draw calls and state changes). And, btw., as stated in the there, this is not a sustainable way of text rendering in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

To remove box around text(ASSUMING YOU HAVE GL_DEPTH_TEST ENABLED):
Disable GL_DEPTH_TEST
before drawing your text
Enable GL_DEPTH_TEST after rendering text

Comment: That's a guess. It may suppress the symptom in your case, but if done right depth remains untouched. After the scene has been rendered the text is rendered with alpha blending enabled.

Comment: @a_donda I have enable alpha blending im still getting a box  around my text

Comment: Its not a depth test problem. Depth test can complete hide glyph, but cant create rect.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков  As you can see from the image i get this box around my text when i don't disable and reenable depth test..... I want to use the text as a UI like life left ect.....  That doesn't interact with the world cords but just the window cords

Comment: Its not a depth test problem. Warch your draw order, you should draw text last.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков I try drawing  my text last....My triangle draws over my text and now i cant see it

Comment: Now when you draw text last you see triangle over your text, and now its a depth test problem. For correct draw text(and other gui stuff) you should: 1)Draw gui last. 2) Disable depth test. 3) Enable blending.